# Windows 10 - Docker Desktop - Kubernetes

Tags: windows-10, docker, kubernetes, docker-registry

having a Windows 10 I decided to install Docker Desktop for learning all about Docker.
Following this, as a second thing was, to learn Kubernetes.

By default Docker Desktop (v4.21.1) gives me the possibility to have Kubernetes (v1.27.2) running inside Docker.

My question is:
How can I use the local images (stored in the local Docker registry) inside of this Kubernetes?

Suggestions are welcome.